# How can i create custom log file using laravel 4.2 version?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change the log format in the 4.2 version of laravel. But I have no idea about this.
Please help me to find the solution or guide me to solve my problem.

I searched a lot on google but still had no success.

**Format**

```
public const SIMPLE_FORMAT = "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%\n";
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may consider updating your laravel system. From 5.6 you can configure it easily with adding an enviroment variable. More details:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging

Comment: Can you provide solution for 4.2?